# xmlNode.children not working after two levels of childrens

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing, xmlnode

sample code

```
sibling = xmlNode.children
grandcihld = sibling.children
print greatgrandchild.prop('name')          // works fine
greatgrandchild = grandcihld.children
print greatgrandchild.prop('name')          // does not work
```

Up to what level we can use xmlnode.children ? is there any restriction over this ?

Comment: What package are you using? Please post XML content.

Comment: I am using ElementTree of libxml2.